# How does react update part of the DOM?

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

I know that this subject has been discussed a lot obviously, but I'm not sure how to research my question that is rather specific and I hope it follows the rules here.

I know that to decide whether to update the DOM or not, react compares the virtual DOM with the re-rendered one. But I just didn't understand if in case it does decide to update it - does it update all the elements of the specific re-rendered component, or does it know to update only the changed elements of the componenet?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: this is a simplistic answer, but it should answer your question. when state changes, your ENTIRE application tree is re-rendered to the virtual dom. then the virtual dom is diffed against the LAST virtual dom, and the necessary DOM elements are changed. it doesn't matter whatsoever which components were invovled that generate the vdoms

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A good place to get a better understanding of how react decides to re-render elements is the [reconciliation documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) but I can summarize:

**Every time render() is called** react will create a new virtual DOM where the root node is the component whose render function is called. The render() function is called when either the state **or** the props of a component or any of its children change. The render() function destroys all of the old virtual DOM nodes starting from the root and creates a brand new virtual DOM.

In order to make sure the re-rendering of components is smooth and efficient React uses the [Diffing Algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) to reduce the time it takes to create a new tree to a time complexity of O(n), usually time complexity for copying trees is > O(n^2). The way it accomplishes this is by using the "key" attribute on each of the elements in the DOM. React knows that instead of creating each element from scratch it can check the "key" attribute on each node in the DOM. This is why you get a warning if you don't set the "key" attribute of each element, React uses the keys to vastly increase its rendering speed.

Comment: As an addendum to this, React doesn't use keys explicitly as a one-to-one between creating an Element and the DOM node it references. With the introduction of Fiber, React uses the Fiber nodes as the correlation between the Element describing what you want and the DOM node you end up with.

Comment: "The render() function destroys all of the old virtual DOM nodes starting from the root and creates a brand new virtual DOM." I was looking to confirm this but can you please site the source as I didn't find this exact info in doc link you provided (to rephrase what I understood: WHOLE virtual DOM is recreated from scratch if any child element down the element tree is re-rendered).

Answer (score 10):

Execution of the `render()` method does not mean that react also renders the actual DOM.
React keeps two copies of the virtual DOM i.e. the old virtual DOM and the re-rendered virtual DOM which gets created when the `render()` method is called.

The output of the `render()` method is a javascript object which is mapped to a DOM element. When a component is changed, we get a new react element. It then compares the new react element and its children in the re-rendered virtual DOM with the element and its children in the old virtual  DOM. If any differences found, it then updates the real DOM only at the places where something has changed (e.g Text of the button has changed) and not update the entire real DOM. If no differences found, the real DOM is not touched.